# Ajax com java, via jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

preciso passar a informação de um componente que está na página jsp para um controler que está em java.

Pelo que entendi a melhor maneira é via AJAX.

Componente municipio

```
<label for="municipio"><font style="color: red">*</font> Munic&iacute;pios</label>
<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="municipio" name="municipio" 
            data-placeholder="Selecione um munic&iacute;pio">
<option value="-1"></option>
<c:forEach var="entidade" items="${listaEntidades}">
<option value="${entidade.id}">${entidade.municpio.codigoNome}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

As informações estão mostrando corretamente na tela.

Preciso desta informação do componente id="municipio" name="municipio", para fazer ações na classe Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Se for pra chamar a servlet no jquery é simples ó

```
<label for="municipio"><font style="color: red">*</font> Munic&iacute;pios</label>
<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="municipio" name="municipio" 
            data-placeholder="Selecione um munic&iacute;pio">
         <option value="">Selecione</option>

         <option value="M">Manaus</option>
         <option value="S">São Paulo</option>
         <option value="R">Rio de Janeiro</option>

</select>
```

Ai o no seu javascript ficaria assim

```
 $('.chosen-select').on('change', function () {
        var cidade = document.getElementById('municipio').value;
        alert('Codigo da cidade: '+cidade);
        $.post("servlet",
            {
                'cidade': cidade,
                'acao': "B"
            },
            function(data){
                         /*seu codigo*/
            });
    });
```

Perceba que na url eu só chamei a servlet respectivamente mapeada

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/s2ofgga7/7/

Comment: Obrigado Carlos

Mas entrei no seu exemplo e ele não mostra o "alert("cidade: "+cidade);", após escolher uma cidade.

O que pode ser ?

Comment: pronto. editei pra você visualizar

Comment: funcionou.

Mas o que devo colocar aqui?

function(data){
/*seu codigo*/
}

Por exemplo, como chamar um controlle do spring ?

Comment: o retorno, recomendo o json, ai seria mais ou menos `if(data.retorno == 1) alert('Feito com sucesso!');`